# OnClickListner unfortunately has stopped

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I wrote a piece of simple code and it causes the app stops working. I found where the error appears (OnClickListner)but I don't know how to solve it

```
    package com.example.alireza.mygrocerylist.Activities.Activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.alireza.mygrocerylist.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private EditText groceryItem, quantity;
    private Button saveButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                //        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                createPopupDialog();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    **private  void createPopupDialog() {
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        groceryItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.groceryItem);
        quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.geroceryQty);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButtom);
        dialogBuilder.setView(view);
        dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveGroceryToDB(v);
            }
        });**



    }

    private void saveGroceryToDB(View v) {

    }

    public boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //here you can start your activity, i.e. this way:
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

when the codes executes and during the run it comes to createPopupDialog(), I got the error unfortunately, My Grocery List has stopped! but if I take out
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() and its override method app works again!
Can you help me please to to ride of this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: change this `groceryItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.groceryItem)` to `groceryItem = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.groceryItem)`. similarly all the other views

Comment: 1) I did the exact thing that topic said. 2) I mean by that method my app does work and if I put comment on that method app works. 3) Thank you but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views of a dialog cannot be accessed directly. Please do like this:-

```
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
groceryItem = view.findViewById(R.id.groceryItem);
```

//Similarly, do for other views

Comment: 05-29 12:08:57.104 12459-12459/com.example.alireza.mygrocerylist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alireza.mygrocerylist, PID: 12459
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: You should do as - saveButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveButtom);